# Navigating multiple objects by links without repetition

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I am trying to navigate through a bunch of objects with links to other objects. I want to start with id of 1 and navigate through each of the objects. Some of the objects will loop back to previous objects, so I want to make sure I look at each one only once otherwise I will get stuck in an infinite loop. I also want to be able to tell which objects cannot be accessed by navigating through the links. I don't think the order of navigation matters.

Here is a sample dataset I might encounter (my actual data will be coming from a database):

```
<?php

$obj_array = [] ;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 1;
$obj->name = "Apple";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 3;
$obj->name = "Carrot";
$obj->link = array(1, 14, 3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 4;
$obj->name = "Dill";
$obj->link = array(1, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 5;
$obj->name = "Egg";
$obj->link = array(6);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 6;
$obj->name = "Fred";
$obj->link = array(7);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 7;
$obj->name = "Goat";
$obj->link = array(7, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 8;
$obj->name = "Harry";
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 9;
$obj->name = "Igloo";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 10;
$obj->name = "Jason";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 11;
$obj->name = "Klaus";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 10);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 14;
$obj->name = "Banana";
$obj->link = array(3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 15;
$obj->name = "Oyster1";
$obj->link = array(16);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 16;
$obj->name = "Oyster2";
$obj->link = array(15);
$obj_array[] = $obj;
```

I would expect to see something like this (order doesn't matter):

**Processed:**

```
Apple
Banana
Carrot
Egg
Fred
Goat
Harry
```

**Not Linked:**

```
Dill
Igloo
Jason
Klaus
Oyster1
Oyster2
```

How can I create a loop to loop through a structure like this especially when each object can have multiple links?

Comment: The objects you provided are not really linked in the sense that you cannot navigate from one object to the next because the object doesn't hold an actual *reference* to another, just an integer matching the other object's `id` value.  You also fail to clearly define the API with which you're working. Typically in network traversal problem, the input isn't the whole network (it's typically too large), but just a node/root. So I'm guessing that the function you want may not take the whole object array as an input.

Comment: Another thing: do you mean for objects to link to themselves (egg and goat do that)?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes, if I'm understanding you, you are correct on both accounts. Objects are being fetched out of the database based on ownership. Each user will have their own personal objects with links to other objects that they own. So, the objects returned will be a subset of the entire database table.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes, though not too likely, objects are able to be linked to themselves. I tried to consider each possible scenario in my test data here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [@wizards answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45926587/434949) worked, I felt I wanted to make a version with a bit clearer code. Below version returns an object with the linked and unlined elements, and I believe it's very clear how it works.

The reason I want to work like this, is to be able to extend it for future questions. Like "How many times is an item linked" or "Which has the most links". It can be easily adapted to answer these questions also.

Another benefit is that it uses as limited loops as possible, which could speed things up quite a bit when the size increases.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$obj_array = [] ;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 1;
$obj->name = "Apple";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 3;
$obj->name = "Carrot";
$obj->link = array(1, 14, 3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 4;
$obj->name = "Dill";
$obj->link = array(1, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 5;
$obj->name = "Egg";
$obj->link = array(6);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 6;
$obj->name = "Fred";
$obj->link = array(7);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 7;
$obj->name = "Goat";
$obj->link = array(7, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 8;
$obj->name = "Harry";
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 9;
$obj->name = "Igloo";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 10;
$obj->name = "Jason";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 11;
$obj->name = "Klaus";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 10);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 14;
$obj->name = "Banana";
$obj->link = array(3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 15;
$obj->name = "Oyster1";
$obj->link = array(16);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 16;
$obj->name = "Oyster2";
$obj->link = array(15);
$obj_array[] = $obj;


/*
 * CALL
 */

$parser = new ObjectLinker($obj_array, 1);

//dump found
//decode/encode to only show public values
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($parser)));


/*
 * ACTUAL CODE
 */


class ObjectLinker
{
    private $_array;
    private $_start;

    public $LinkedElements = array();
    public $UnLinkedElements = array();

    final public function __construct($ar, $start)
    {
        $this->_array = $ar;
        $this->_start = $start;

        $this->getElementsArray();
        $this->findLinked($this->_start);
    }

    final private function getElementsArray()
    {       
            //since each Id is unique, i'm using the ID as the key in the array. this will allow faster access
            //Ofcourse it would be better if you would create the array like this in the first place, then you can skip this step
            foreach($this->_array as $obj) {
                if (!is_null($obj) && property_exists($obj, 'id')) {
                    //I add everything to the unlinked elements. We will remove the linked once, to have once less loop
                    $this->UnLinkedElements[$obj->id] = $obj;
                }
            }
    }


    final private function findLinked($id)
    {
        //If the key is not in the array, it's already loaded
        if (!array_key_exists($id, $this->UnLinkedElements)) {
            return;
        }

        //get obj
        //Because of the getElementsArray() step, I'm already sure the object exists.
        //If you change the input array, you might want to check for invalid obj
        $obj = $this->UnLinkedElements[$id];

        //add to linked
        $this->LinkedElements[$id] = $obj;

        //remove from unlinked
        unset($this->UnLinkedElements[$id]);

        //no links
        if (!property_exists($obj, 'link')) {
            return;
        }

        $links = $obj->link;

        //Invalid links
        if (!is_array($links)) {
            return;
        }

        //check links
        foreach($links as $link) {
            $this->findLinked($link);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [LinkedElements] => stdClass Object
    (
      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 1
          [name] => Apple
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 14
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [14] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 14
          [name] => Banana
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 3
            )

        )

      [3] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 3
          [name] => Carrot
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 14
              [2] => 3
            )

        )

      [5] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 5
          [name] => Egg
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 6
            )

        )

      [6] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 6
          [name] => Fred
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 7
            )

        )

      [7] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 7
          [name] => Goat
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 7
              [1] => 8
            )

        )

      [8] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 8
          [name] => Harry
        )

    )

  [UnLinkedElements] => stdClass Object
    (
      [4] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 4
          [name] => Dill
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [9] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 9
          [name] => Igloo
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 14
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [10] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 10
          [name] => Jason
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
              [2] => 8
            )

        )

      [11] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 11
          [name] => Klaus
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
              [2] => 10
            )

        )

      [15] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 15
          [name] => Oyster1
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 16
            )

        )

      [16] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 16
          [name] => Oyster2
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 15
            )

        )

    )

)
```

Comment: Thank you Hugo. After testing your answer is the most efficient one so far for speed, is easier to understand, and is nice to have a reusable object set.

Comment: If you have a chance please see my most recent question.

Comment: In the most cases any code can be improved for speed, memory, efficience, etc.. we're just used different paradigms OOP versus FP :) and, unfortunately, PHP doesn't support tail recursion optimization, although your code can't use it, in case when this ability would be exists ) Anyway, thanks for the code! :)

Comment: @kojow7 don't ask a new question with 95% the same content. Update this question with your table structure or just ask a question "How can I get this table structure to this object structure" and link to this question to the reason why you need it. With the second option,you'll have a lot more responses.

Comment: @HugoDelsing, the thing is if I modify my question, it will invalidate the effort that everyone put in to answer my question, and they are good answers. Asking a second question about converting the table structure might work, but will may not be as efficient as leaving the structure the way it is now as extra work would have to be done just to convert it.

Answer (score 5):

You can skip the printing and work with the `$obj_array` itself, diving the data into two arrays is just to be able to print them nicely:

```
$linked_ids = array();
$processed_objects = array();
$unlinked_objects = array();

foreach ( $obj_array as $obj ) {
    if ( isset($obj->link) && $obj->link ) {
        $linked_ids = array_merge($linked_ids, $obj->link);
    }
}

$linked_ids = array_unique( $linked_ids );

foreach ($obj_array as $obj) {
    if ( !in_array($obj->id, $linked_ids) ) {
        $unlinked_objects[] = $obj;
    } else {
        $processed_objects[] = $obj;
    }
}

/* Printing */

echo '<b>Processed:</b><br>';

foreach ( $processed_objects as $obj ) {
    echo $obj->name . '<br>';
}

echo '<b>Not Linked:</b><br>';

foreach ( $unlinked_objects as $obj ) {
    echo $obj->name . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: While your code seemed quite promising at first, it does not work for all situations. I updated my example above. You will notice that your code incorrectly processes objects #10, 15, and 16. I am certainly open to other suggestions.

Comment: Klaus(#11) is linking to Jason(#10) and the same goes to #15 links to #16 and vise versa!?

Comment: Hi Plamen, yes, users can define links in any direction and to any object, even themselves as is seen in Goat(#7).

Comment: I see, but why #10, #15 and #16 should be outputted in "Not Linked"?

Comment: Because if you start at #1, there is no way to get to any of those other numbers by following the links. #1 will always be the starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Answer updated, now the code walks through an array started with ID=1, collects all the "connection" links that meets on the run and show names of objects out.
I hope desirable result is achieved.

The first list (before line of dashes) is the list that can be accessible from object with ID=1 through the connected links.

The second one is missed names.

The code:

```
<?php

$obj_array = [] ;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 1;
$obj->name = "Apple";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 3;
$obj->name = "Carrot";
$obj->link = array(1, 14, 3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 4;
$obj->name = "Dill";
$obj->link = array(1, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 5;
$obj->name = "Egg";
$obj->link = array(6);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 6;
$obj->name = "Fred";
$obj->link = array(7);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 7;
$obj->name = "Goat";
$obj->link = array(7, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 8;
$obj->name = "Harry";
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 9;
$obj->name = "Igloo";
$obj->link = array(14, 5);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 10;
$obj->name = "Jason";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 8);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 11;
$obj->name = "Klaus";
$obj->link = array(1, 5, 10);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 14;
$obj->name = "Banana";
$obj->link = array(3);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 15;
$obj->name = "Oyster1";
$obj->link = array(16);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->id = 16;
$obj->name = "Oyster2";
$obj->link = array(15);
$obj_array[] = $obj;

function findObject($objects, $id) {
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        if ($object->id === $id) {
            return $object;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getLinkedIds($objects, $startId=1) {
    $idQueue = [$startId];
    $linkedIds = [];
    while (count($idQueue)) {
        $id = array_pop($idQueue);
        $obj = findObject($objects, $id);
        if (!is_null($obj) && property_exists($obj, 'link')) {
            $linksToAdd = array_filter($obj->link, function($linkedId) use ($linkedIds) {
                return !in_array($linkedId, $linkedIds);
            });
            $idQueue = array_merge($idQueue, $linksToAdd);
        }
        $linkedIds[] = $id;
    }
    return array_unique($linkedIds);
}

function getNotLinkedObjects($objects, $startId=1) {
    $linked = getLinkedIds($objects, $startId);
    return array_filter($objects, function($obj) use ($linked) {
        return !in_array($obj->id, $linked);
    });
}

function getLinkedObjects($objects, $startId=1) {
    $linked = getLinkedIds($objects, $startId);
    return array_filter($objects, function($obj) use ($linked) {
        return in_array($obj->id, $linked);
    });
}

function listNames($objects) {
    foreach ($objects as $obj) {
        echo $obj->name.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

listNames(getLinkedObjects($obj_array));
echo '----'.PHP_EOL;
listNames(getNotLinkedObjects($obj_array));
```

result:

```
Apple
Carrot
Egg
Fred
Goat
Harry
Banana
---
Dill
Igloo
Jason
Klaus
Oyster1
Oyster2
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately your code does not work in all situations. I have update my example. Using my new example, your code incorrectly processes Jason, Oyster1, and Oyster2.

Comment: @kojow7 I've updated the answer, but my result slightly different of your :-/

Comment: I am a bit confused as to where $startId is coming from. Without that there is no value for $idQueue.

Comment: @kojow7 Oh.. my alopogies.. just forgot to add to the source, fixed )

Comment: Thank you. :) And, yeah, for some reason it is handling the "Banana" and "Carrot" ones incorrectly.

Comment: @kojow7 updated source with your updated objects list, enjoy the results :D

Comment: Aww, shoot, thank you very much. In updating SO and my own code I had a discrepancy between the two. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

#### Note I made some assumptions to better reflect a typical real-life network problem

1. I assumed that in production, the full network of objects is too large to hold in memory. This means that the right approach must take just one root node and discover all linked objects without duplication
2. I assumed that each ID in `$obj->link` can be resolved to a linked object using a DB or other query. To simplify the code (so I don't have to write a `getObjAtID()` function) I changed the interface of link from `$obj->link = [id1, id2]` to `$obj->link = [objectRef1, objectRef2]`

My code:

```
function processObjNetwork(stdClass $rootObj){
    $linkedObjects = [];

    $process = function(stdClass $obj) use(&$linkedObjects, &$process){
        if(isset($linkedObjects[$obj->id])) return; // already processed
        else $linkedObjects[$obj->id] = $obj; // add to linked

        if(empty($obj->link)) return; // nothing linked; no recursion needed

        foreach($obj->link as $child) $process($child); // recursion to linked objs
    };

    $process($rootObj); // start with the root node
    return $linkedObjects;
}
```

What gets returned is a collection of all linked objects:

```
$linkedObjects = processObjNetwork($rootObject); // root here is 'Apple'
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/RioL7)

Given my assumption -- specifically that the map is too large so we start with only a root node -- it is not possible to discover unlinked nodes since by definition they are not connected to the root.

If you have all the nodes in storage, you can find unlinked nodes by simply iterating through every node and checking whether it is found among linked. If not, then it's unlinked.

```
$unlinkedObjects = [];
foreach($obj_array as $obj){ 
  // add to $unlinkedObjects anything not found in $linkedObjects 
  if(!isset($linkedObjects[$obj->id])) $unlinkedObjects[$obj->id] = $obj;
}
```

Comment: While I think the concept is good, the database that I am retrieving the data from stores the links as id numbers, not object references. I think there will be a fair bit of overhead trying to convert the ids into object references.

Comment: @kojow7 you misunderstand. You don't need to do any conversion of your DB structure. All you need is a getter function that retrieves the object at that id from the DB.  This is what I assumed you would do (look at the 1st sentence of my 2nd assumption again). So to adapt this code to your setup, you need to replace `$obj->link` in my code with a `query($obj->link)` function that returns the array of linked objects from the DB.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I need to be able to alert the users that they have objects that have not yet been linked to the main structure. Also, while you have definitely given me something to think about for down the road, for now I think that any selected data set would have at most a few hundred objects that I'd have to look through.