# Determining which objects are or are not linked to the main root object

Tags: php, mysql, loops, object

I am trying to navigate through a bunch of objects with links to other objects. I want to start with the lowest id number (the root object) and navigate through each of the objects based on connected links. Some of the object links will loop back to previous objects, so I want to make sure I look at each one only once otherwise I will get stuck in an infinite loop. I also want to be able to tell which objects cannot be accessed by navigating through the links beginning at the first link.

The tables in my database look like this:

Object Table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | title   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Apple   |
|  3 | Carrot  |
|  4 | Dill    |
|  5 | Egg     |
|  6 | Fred    |
|  7 | Goat    |
|  8 | Harry   |
|  9 | Igloo   |
| 10 | Jason   |
| 11 | Klaus   |
| 12 | Banana  |
| 15 | Oyster1 |
| 16 | Oyster2 |
+----+---------+
```

Object_Links Table:

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| id |  obj_id |  obj_link_id |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 |           12 |
|  2 |       1 |            5 |
|  3 |       3 |            1 |
|  4 |       3 |           12 |
|  5 |       3 |            3 |
|  6 |       4 |            1 |
|  7 |       4 |            5 |
|  8 |       5 |            6 |
|  9 |       6 |            7 |
| 10 |       7 |            7 |
| 11 |       7 |            8 |
| 12 |       9 |           12 |
| 13 |       9 |            5 |
| 14 |      10 |            1 |
| 15 |      10 |            5 |
| 16 |      10 |            8 |
| 17 |      11 |            1 |
| 18 |      11 |            5 |
| 19 |      11 |           10 |
| 20 |      12 |            3 |
| 21 |      15 |           16 |
| 22 |      16 |           15 |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

So, from the table you can see that object 1 has links to both objects 12 and 5.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select  object.id, title, obj_link_id
    from  object
    left join  object_links  ON object.id = object_links.object_id
    order by  object.id
```

which gives the table:

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | title   |  obj_link_id |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 | Apple   |           12 |
|  1 | Apple   |            5 |
|  3 | Carrot  |            1 |
|  3 | Carrot  |           12 |
|  3 | Carrot  |            3 |
|  4 | Dill    |            1 |
|  4 | Dill    |            5 |
|  5 | Egg     |            6 |
|  6 | Fred    |            7 |
|  7 | Goat    |            7 |
|  7 | Goat    |            8 |
|  8 | Harry   |         NULL |
|  9 | Igloo   |           12 |
|  9 | Igloo   |            5 |
| 10 | Jason   |            1 |
| 10 | Jason   |            5 |
| 10 | Jason   |            8 |
| 11 | Klaus   |            1 |
| 11 | Klaus   |            5 |
| 11 | Klaus   |           10 |
| 12 | Banana  |            3 |
| 15 | Oyster1 |           16 |
| 16 | Oyster2 |           15 |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

In PHP I am using:

```
$objects = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

I wasn't sure whether there was a better way to fetch these for my purposes so am open to suggestions.

A `print_r($objects)` yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Apple
            [obj_link_id] => 12
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Apple
            [obj_link_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Carrot
            [obj_link_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Carrot
            [obj_link_id] => 12
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Carrot
            [obj_link_id] => 3
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Dill
            [obj_link_id] => 1
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Dill
            [obj_link_id] => 5
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Egg
            [obj_link_id] => 6
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Fred
            [obj_link_id] => 7
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => Goat
            [obj_link_id] => 7
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => Goat
            [obj_link_id] => 8
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [title] => Harry
            [obj_link_id] =>
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [title] => Igloo
            [obj_link_id] => 12
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [title] => Igloo
            [obj_link_id] => 5
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [title] => Jason
            [obj_link_id] => 1
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [title] => Jason
            [obj_link_id] => 5
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [title] => Jason
            [obj_link_id] => 8
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [title] => Klaus
            [obj_link_id] => 1
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [title] => Klaus
            [obj_link_id] => 5
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [title] => Klaus
            [obj_link_id] => 10
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [title] => Banana
            [obj_link_id] => 3
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [title] => Oyster1
            [obj_link_id] => 16
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [title] => Oyster2
            [obj_link_id] => 15
        )

)
```

Please note, that the number in the brackets is just the array index, not the object id number, so don't let the index throw you off.

I am trying to find a way to determine which are the linked and which are the unlinked objects. Based on the above scenario the objects should be separated as follows:

```
**Linked:**

    Apple
    Banana
    Carrot
    Egg
    Fred
    Goat
    Harry

**Not Linked:**

    Dill
    Igloo
    Jason
    Klaus
    Oyster1
    Oyster2
```

**My main question:**

How can I create a loop in PHP to loop through a structure like this especially when each object can have multiple links? Ultimately I would like to produce two collections of objects, one containing the linked objects and one containing the unlinked objects. A sample collection might look like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [LinkedElements] => stdClass Object
    (
      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 1
          [name] => Apple
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 14
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [14] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 14
          [name] => Banana
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 3
            )

        )

      [3] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 3
          [name] => Carrot
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 14
              [2] => 3
            )

        )

      [5] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 5
          [name] => Egg
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 6
            )

        )

      [6] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 6
          [name] => Fred
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 7
            )

        )

      [7] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 7
          [name] => Goat
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 7
              [1] => 8
            )

        )

      [8] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 8
          [name] => Harry
        )

    )

  [UnLinkedElements] => stdClass Object
    (
      [4] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 4
          [name] => Dill
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [9] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 9
          [name] => Igloo
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 14
              [1] => 5
            )

        )

      [10] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 10
          [name] => Jason
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
              [2] => 8
            )

        )

      [11] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 11
          [name] => Klaus
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 1
              [1] => 5
              [2] => 10
            )

        )

      [15] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 15
          [name] => Oyster1
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 16
            )

        )

      [16] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 16
          [name] => Oyster2
          [link] => Array
            (
              [0] => 15
            )

        )

    )

)
```

Please note:

- Navigation is done from object to link, not the other way around.
- It is okay to have an object point to itself (as object 7 does).
- The above sample structure (underneath my main question) is a suggestion only and I am open to other suggestions.
- Disclaimer: This question is based on another question I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925955/navigating-multiple-objects-by-links-without-repetition).
  In my original question I manually created the test objects, but I was not able to pull them out of my database in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier (IMHO) to deal with the data as two separate arrays.  A set of objects and their links.  Also, as the first part I convert the object to have the ID as the key, this allows me to use it directly rather than having to search for the ID each time.

Also to make the solution a lot simpler, I've created a flag in the object array as I visit it, so that when I try and reference it again, I can check if it's already been visited.

```
<?php 
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$objects =[[1,'apple'],
        [3, 'Carrot'],
        [4, 'Dill'],
        [5, 'Egg '],
        [6, 'Fred'],
        [7, 'Goat'],
        [8, 'Harry'],
        [9, 'Igloo'],
        [10, 'Jason'],
        [11, 'Klaus'],
        [12, 'Banana'],
        [15, 'Oyster1'],
        [16, 'Oyster2' ]];
$links =[[1,12],
        [1,5],
        [3,1],
        [3,12],
        [3,3],
        [4,1],
        [4,5],
        [5,6],
        [6,7],
        [7,7],
        [7,8],
        [8,null],
        [9,12],
        [9,5],
        [10,1],
        [10,5],
        [10,8],
        [11,1],
        [11,5],
        [11,10],
        [12,3],
        [15,16],
        [16,15 ]];

function buildTree ( $id, &$objects, $links )   {
    foreach ( $links as $testNode )    {
        if ( $testNode[0] == $id && 
                $testNode[1] != $id &&
                $testNode[1] != null &&
                !isset($objects[$testNode[1]]['visited']) )    {
            $objects[$testNode[1]]['visited'] = true;
            buildTree ( $testNode[1], $objects, $links);
        }
    }
}

// Convert array to have the ID as key
$objects = array_combine(array_column($objects, 0), $objects);
// Fetch ID of first item
reset($objects);
$startID = key($objects);
// Mark as visited
$objects[$startID]['visited'] = true;
// Process
buildTree ( $startID, $objects, $links);

$linked = [];
$notLinked = [];
foreach ( $objects as $object)  {
    if ( isset($object['visited']) )    {
        $linked[] = $object[1];
    }
    else    {
        $notLinked[] = $object[1];
    }
}
echo "Linked...".PHP_EOL;
print_r($linked);

echo "Not linked...".PHP_EOL;
print_r($notLinked);
```

As you can see, the core is the recursive `buildTree` function. This uses `&$objects` as this means that all calls to the function will use the same array.  As I want to build up all the uses of the items, this is important.

The condition in buildTree, checks to see if it's the node we want, it's not referring to the same node (waste of time looking any more), not null (not sure why you link to null, but again not worth looking any further) and that the node hasn't already been visited. If these conditions are OK, it marks the next node as visited and goes down into the next level.

The output is...

```
Linked...
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => Carrot
    [2] => Egg 
    [3] => Fred
    [4] => Goat
    [5] => Harry
    [6] => Banana
)
Not linked...
Array
(
    [0] => Dill
    [1] => Igloo
    [2] => Jason
    [3] => Klaus
    [4] => Oyster1
    [5] => Oyster2
)
```

Comment: Technically object 8 has no links, so that is why the results of the SQL query indicate that it is linking to NULL. I was originally joining the two tables together, but based on your and Weltschmerz's answer, it looks like not joining them would be the better approach.

Comment: It's more a case of being aware of what certain things mean, if you include it then deal with it appropriately, excluding it is perhaps easier.  As long as you can cater for each possibility, then your fine, but when I didn't exclude it - my code initially created a link to a new entry of `null` and just looked odd.

Comment: I have discovered that I was can make your code a bit more efficient by using "PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE"  to fetch the data from the database. That way I do not need to convert the array and can eliminate the array_combine line.

Comment: It's always useful to know how to improve any code you write, thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) problem. Starting from a node (root) you want to traverse the graph keeping track of each node visited along the way. Once the traversal is over, visited ones are connected. Breadth-first search can be done in this way:

```
//To form a graph fetch all objects from the database (sorted by id) and 
//index them in a hash map
$objects = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$nodes = [];
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $nodes[$object->id] = new Node($object);
}

//fetch all connections from the database and link the objects
$links = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $nodes[$link->obj_id]->addLink($nodes[$link->obj_link_id]);
}

//let's assume root is the first node (sorted by id), 
//traverse the graph starting from root
$root = reset($nodes);
$root->traverse();

//now if a node can be reached by the root it is marked as visited
$linked = [];
$notLinked = [];
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->isVisited()) {
        $linked[] = $node;
    } else {
        $notLinked[] = $node;
    }
}
```

And the node class:

```
class Node
{

    /**
     * List of neighbor nodes.
     *
     * @var Node[]
     */
    private $links = [];

    /**
     * id, title info
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $data = [];

    /**
     * To track visited nodes.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $visited = false;

    /**
     * Node constructor.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    /**
     * Add a link to this node.
     *
     * @param Node $node
     * @return void
     */
    public function addLink(Node $node)
    {
        $this->links[] = $node;
    }

    /**
     * Traverse the graph in a Breadth-First-Search fashion marking
     * every visited node.
     * @return void
     */
    public function traverse()
    {
        //initialize queue
        $q = new SplQueue();

        //add root to queue and mark as visited
        $q->enqueue($this);
        $this->visited = true;

        while (!$q->isEmpty()) {
            /** @var Node $cur */
            $cur = $q->dequeue();

            foreach ($cur->links as $link) {

                //if link not visited already add it to queue and mark visited
                if (!$link->visited) {
                    $link->visited = true;
                    $q->enqueue($link);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if node has been visited.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isVisited()
    {
        return $this->visited;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I run this and try to do print_r($linked) or print_r($notLinked) I get a huge list of deeply nested objects with the message "*RECURSION*" printed out. Is this what I should be expecting?

Comment: `$linked` and `$notLinked` are collections of Node objects. Depending on your application you want them (Node objects) to do something useful (using the data they've been provided with in the constructor). You could also have a Node just return the data with something like `getData()`. Up to you.

The point is that `$linked` should contain nodes that can be reached from the root, and `$notLinked` the rest of the nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the "root" is `obj_id 1`.

Here's a somewhat brute force algorithm, but it takes advantage of SQL's liking of 'set' operations.

```
Insert into table1 the root (1)
Loop
    Create table2 with all nodes linked to any node in table1
    Exit if number of rows in table2 = num rows in table1
    table1 := table2
```

Closer to SQL:

```
# Initialize:
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    obj_id ...
    PRIMARY KEY(obj_id)
)
    SELECT 1;   # assuming root is 1

start of loop:
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    obj_id ...
    PRIMARY KEY(obj_id)
)
    SELECT DISTINCT obj_link_id
        FROM table1
        JOIN object_links USING(obj_id);

SELECT @fini := ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 ) = 
                ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 )   # will give true/false
DROP TABLE table1;
RENAME TABLE table2 TO table1;
loop if @fini=0
```

The output is all the 'connected' ids.  If you want the unconnected ones:

```
SELECT obj_id
    FROM object_links
    LEFT JOIN table1 USING(obj_id)
    WHERE table1.obj_id IS NULL;   # that is, missing from table1
```

Comment: I think my preference would be to do this in PHP rather than creating new tables in the database. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: OK.  PHP's array_merge could be used to combine the array "tables2" into "table1".  So, the question is really about algorithms, not PHP or MySQL.

Comment: I also am a bit confused as to which two tables you are referring to. I have already combined the Object table and the Object Links table in my SQL select statement.

Comment: My bad.  I should have used `object_links`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty short way to get all linked IDs:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_obj_link', 'testread', 'testread');

$links = $pdo
    ->query('select obj_id, obj_link_id from object_links')
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

function getLinks($objId, $links,  $indirectNodes = []) {
    $directNodes = isset($links[$objId]) ? $links[$objId] : [];
    foreach($directNodes as $linkedNode) {
        if (!in_array($linkedNode, $indirectNodes)) {
            $indirectNodes[] = $linkedNode;
            $indirectNodes = array_unique(array_merge(
                $indirectNodes,
                getLinks($linkedNode, $links, $indirectNodes)
            ));
        }
    }
    return $indirectNodes;
}

$linkedObjectIds = getLinks(1, $links);
```

`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` will return a structured array with links per object indexed by objectIDs which looks like:

```
$links = [
    1  => ['5', '12'],
    3  => ['1', '3', '12'],
    4  => ['1', '5'],
    5  => ['6'],
    6  => ['7'],
    7  => ['7', '8'],
    9  => ['5', '12'],
    10 => ['1', '5', '8'],
    11 => ['1', '5', '10'],
    12 => ['3'],
    15 => ['16'],
    16 => ['15'],
];
```

The `getLinks`function will "walk" the `$links` array recursively and merge all child arrays that are found on the way. Since PHP doesn't seem to have an `array_union` function - `array_unique(array_merge(..))` is used instead.

The result:

```
$linkedObjectIds = array (
  0 => '5',
  1 => '6',
  2 => '7',
  3 => '8',
  4 => '12',
  10 => '3',
  11 => '1',
)
```

Note that the indexes have no meaning here.

To get the corresponding objects you can do the following:

```
$objects = $pdo
    ->query('select id, title from object')
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$linkedObjects = array_intersect_key($objects, array_flip($linkedObjectIds));
$notLinkedObjects = array_diff_key($objects, $linkedObjects);
```

The variables will contain:

```
$objects = array (
  1 => 'Apple',
  3 => 'Carrot',
  4 => 'Dill',
  5 => 'Egg',
  6 => 'Fred',
  7 => 'Goat',
  8 => 'Harry',
  9 => 'Igloo',
  10 => 'Jason',
  11 => 'Klaus',
  12 => 'Banana',
  15 => 'Oyster1',
  16 => 'Oyster2',
);
$linkedObjects = array (
  1 => 'Apple',
  3 => 'Carrot',
  5 => 'Egg',
  6 => 'Fred',
  7 => 'Goat',
  8 => 'Harry',
  12 => 'Banana',
);
$notLinkedObjects = array (
  4 => 'Dill',
  9 => 'Igloo',
  10 => 'Jason',
  11 => 'Klaus',
  15 => 'Oyster1',
  16 => 'Oyster2',
);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ZQQGE35352

Note that `in_array()` and `array_unique()` are probably slow, since they have to search in values, which are not sorted. This might lead to performance issues on some datasets. Assuming that PHP can search the keys faster, we could use `array_key_exists()` instead of `in_array()` and the array operator `+` (union by keys) instead of `array_unique(array_merge())`. And the code will even be a bit shorter:

```
function getLinks($objId, $links,  $indirectNodes = []) {
    $directNodes = isset($links[$objId]) ? $links[$objId] : [];
    foreach($directNodes as $linkedNode) {
        if (!array_key_exists($linkedNode, $indirectNodes)) {
            $indirectNodes[$linkedNode] = 0;
            $indirectNodes = $indirectNodes + getLinks($linkedNode, $links, $indirectNodes);
        }
    }
    return $indirectNodes;
}
```

However - since the function now returns the needed result as keys, we would need to use `array_keys()` to extract them:

```
$linkedObjectIds = array_keys(getLinks(1, $links));
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GHO7179